# Switch to only display products purchased by logged in user on shopify

Tags: shopify, e-commerce, liquid

I need a switch or checkbox on my site that makes the whole site only display products the logged in user has purchased before, or they can choose to display the whole catalog.

I'm not super keen on editing every product loop shopify uses, so if any of you guys have another idea, I'm very open to it!

Thanks all.

Comment: „ I'm not super keen on editing every product loop shopify uses, so if any of you guys have another idea, I'm very open to it!“ - There probably won‘t be too many other options here besides manipulating the whole website through JavaScript. Depending on how many products a user purchases on average you might need some sort of pagination as well to not hurt the website‘s performance. I‘d go with a server side approach (Liquid) for sure

Comment: Hey david! I ended up going editing the liquid product loop and using a metafield on the customer (turns out there aren't as many product loops in the whole theme as I thought). This works like a charm!! Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Awesome! Why did you decide to create a metafield for this exactly? :)